# Rewrite url in nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js

How can I rewrite urls in Nuxt.js ? I want to rewrite this : 
`mywebsite/user/1` 
to 
`m̀ywebsite/user/alex`

If someone have an answer please tell me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect `/user/1` to `/user/alex` with a `middleware` configuration declared in `<rootDir>/pages/user/_id.vue`. Note the `middleware` method receives a `context` argument, which contains two properties that are particularly useful in your case:

- [`params: Object`](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context#-code-params-code-em-object-em-) -  `params.id` gives the ID parsed from the URL (e.g., `params.id === '222'` for the URL `/user/222`)
- [`redirect: Function`](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context#-code-redirect-code-em-function-em-) - allows you to redirect to another route

*Example usage in `<rootDir>/pages/user/_id.vue`:*

```html
<script>
export default {
  middleware({ params, redirect }) {
    if (params.id === '1') {
      redirect('/users/alex')
    } else {
      redirect('/users/bob')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful but this is not what I want, I don't want to redirect my urls just to rewrite urls. Do you thinks it's possible or I have to change my file call ```user/_id.vue```to ``ùser/_name.vue``` ?

Comment: @Alex What server implementation are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you're saying, can you give me examples of server implementation please ?

Comment: Express, Koa, Apache

Comment: I think it's Apache, but I have a nginx.conf file too :/

Comment: Rewriting url is not a good practice so your best course of action is to use `user/_name.vue` instead of ids

Answer (score 1):

There is a Nuxt.js Redirect module.

[Link here](https://github.com/nuxt-community/redirect-module)

But i think that for what you're trying to do is not recommended to "rewrite" the URL, what you're are trying to do is to change the identifier for the URL, so the API find the user by the username or first name instead from the ID.

In this scenario you'll have to modify the links that points to the users and set something like this.

```
<nuxt-link :to="`/user/${currentUser.username}`">My Profile</nuxt-link>
```

This will be a link like "/user/david" and then in the user profile page you'll have to use **asyncData** to fetch the user profile using the username instead of the ID.

Of course, you'll have also to modify the backend or API for this.

I have made a code sandbox for you, here you'll see what i'm talking about.

Try both alternatives.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-sound-1vmy7)